# How to run aout on linux?

Tags: linux, freebsd

The question is how to execute aout-format binary (I mean old format which for example used on FreeBSD before it has migrated to ELF) on Linux system. Is there a possibility to do so without extra coding (is there some existing solution)? Probably it should be in form of kernel module or patch for the Linux kernel. Another solution could be user-space launcher (may be even run-time linker). I have searched for something similar but was unable to found something. I have not yet checked difference in system calls interfaces, if you have some comments about that, you are welcome to provide them.

P.S. I know that writing user-space launcher for aout static binary is quite trivial but the question is about some existing solution.

Comment: Back when I compiled my own kernels I remembered a kernel option to enable `aout` binary format support in the kernel. I don't know if that was removed in the meantime, however.

Comment: If you want to add updates or clarification, just edit your question.

Answer (score 5):

Check for CONFIG_BINFMT_AOUT in your kernel config.

If your kernel has /proc/config.gz:

```
zgrep CONFIG_BINFMT_AOUT /proc/config.gz
```

On Ubuntu and the like:

```
grep CONFIG_BINFMT_AOUT /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Kernel option was CONFIG_BINFMT_AOUT, not sure if it's still around or necessary.